# Cannot release button in KivyMD

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

Why does the following code not release it when I touch the center of the button?

If I touch the bottom of the button, I can release it,
so I guess there is probably a problem with the coordinate calculation.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase

kv = '''
MDBottomNavigation:
    MDBottomNavigationItem:
        MDTabs:
            MyTab:
                title: 'tab'
                ScrollView:
                    MDRectangleFlatButton:
                        id: button
                        text: self.state
                        font_size: 60
'''


class MyTab(FloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    pass


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


MyApp().run()
```

- python 3.8
- Kivy 2.1.0
- kivymd 1.1.1

Comment: What operating system and display type are you on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with `_do_touch_up`, an internal function of Carousel in Kivy.

It's necessary to write `touch.apply_transform_2d(self.to_widget)` and the associated `push()` and `pop()` in this function.

Answer (score 0):

The button is dynamically changing its length with the content.  So, you need some way to fix its width.

this is just a way to do a test.

```
text: "{:<10}".format(dict(normal= 0, down=8)[self.state])
```

this should keep the button size constant.

Comment: This problem occurs regardless of the button size.

Comment: when I tested it I can see the outline of the button change as I hold it down, and change again as I release it.  I suppose this could depend on the container it is put into.  I read it as either a bug in kivymd or just a shortcoming or my lack of a better way to fix the width of it.